# Multiple sliders by triggering from one function returns setInterval conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, slideshow, setinterval

I'm trying to create an slider function which effects multiple slider elements on the document. Stuck at setInverval value.

[**Here is testing jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/dQVyL/)

[**Works perfect when its just one.**](http://jsfiddle.net/dQVyL/1/)

```
function repSlider(target) {
        target = $(target);
        targetEl = target.find('.drop_leds');
        targetEl.hide().first().addClass('active').show();
        totalEl = targetEl.length-1;

        setInterval(function() {
            curEl = target.find('.active.drop_leds').index();
            curEl == totalEl ? curEl = 0 : curEl += 1;
            console.log(curEl);//this gives bug
            targetEl.hide().removeClass('active')
            .eq(curEl).addClass('active').fadeIn(444);
        },3000);

}

repSlider('.targetClassA');
repSlider('.targetClassB');
```

also tried with different method but result is same.

```
$.fn.repSlider = function() {
        target = $(this);
        targetEl = target.find('.sliderEl');
        targetEl.hide().first().addClass('active').show();
        totalEl = targetEl.length-1;

        return window.setInterval(function() {
            curEl = target.find('.active.sliderEl').index();
            curEl == totalEl ? curEl = 0 : curEl += 1;
            console.log(curEl);//this gives bug
            targetEl.hide().removeClass('active')
            .eq(curEl).addClass('active').fadeIn(444);

    },3000);
}

$('.repSliderA').repSlider();
$('.repSliderB').repSlider();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with getting setInverval out from function:

[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/dQVyL/5/)

```
$('.targetClassA > div').hide().first().addClass('active').show();
$('.targetClassB > div').hide().first().addClass('active').show();
function repSlider(target) {
    target = $(target);
    targetEl = target.find('.drop_leds');
    totalEl = targetEl.length-1;

    curEl = target.find('.active.drop_leds').index();
    curEl == totalEl ? curEl = 0 : curEl += 1;
    console.log(curEl);//this gives bug
    targetEl.hide().removeClass('active')
    .eq(curEl).addClass('active').fadeIn(444);

}

var repSliderAInt = setInterval(function() {
    repSlider('.targetClassA');
},3000);
var repSliderBInt = setInterval(function() {
    repSlider('.targetClassB');
},3000);
```